# ZSH on Linux doesn't recognize valid options in a shell script

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, zsh, shebang

`zsh` doesn't recognize options set with `-o`, but **only** when its in a shebang, and on `Linux`.

The following script fails on `zsh 5.0.2`, `zsh 5.6`, and the latest git:

```
#!/bin/zsh -o pipefail
thiswillfail | echo 'hello, world'
echo $?
exit
```

**Expected Output**

```
hello, world
/home/prajjwal/script:2: command not found: thiswillfail
127
```

**Actual Output**

```
/bin/zsh: no such option:  pipefail
```

**What works**

- The script on `zsh 5.3` on `MacOS Mojave`. This appears to be failing on every `Linux` version I've tried so far, though.
- Manually invoking `/bin/zsh -o pipefail` on a terminal
- Setting the option with `set -o pipefail` **after** the shebang in the script.

**What I've tried**

- Emptying my `.zshrc`'s to ensure one of my settings isn't causing this.

**Aside**

While I'm only trying to get `pipefail` to work, this refuses to work with any other options that I try to set, even though all of them are mentioned in `zshoptions`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pitfall of trying to set options on the `#!` line. The kernel only splits the shebang line at the first space.

When you say

```
#!/bin/zsh -o pipefail
```

the command that ends up being executed is `"/bin/zsh" "-o pipefail" "/home/prajjwal/script"`.

The error message says that `" pipefail"` (note the leading space) is not a valid option, which is correct: Only `"pipefail"` is valid.

In this case a possible workaround is to cram everything into a single command line argument:

```
#!/bin/zsh -opipefail
```

But in general that's not possible and the `#!` interface doesn't let you pass more than one extra argument, so your choices are to find other workarounds (e.g. using `set` manually) or to write a wrapper script:

```
#!/bin/zsh
exec /bin/zsh -o pipefail /path/to/the/real/script
```

---

On some systems another alternative is available: `env -S`. This option is not specified by POSIX and is not available on all systems. It works on [systems using the GNU tools](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/env-invocation.html#g_t_002dS_002f_002d_002dsplit_002dstring-usage-in-scripts) (including all standard Linux distributions) and [FreeBSD](https://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/1/env/), but not [OpenBSD](https://man.openbsd.org/env.1) or [NetBSD](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?env+1+NetBSD-current). I couldn't find any information about MacOS.

(Note: GNU env also supports `--split-string` as an alternative (long) option name, but FreeBSD env does not.)

Usage:

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S /bin/zsh -o pipefail
```

This invokes `env` with a single long argument (`'-S /bin/zsh -o pipefail'`). Standard option processing treats it as the `-S` option followed by an argument (`' /bin/zsh -o pipefail'`).

In a simple case like this, `env -S` splits the argument on spaces/tabs and treats the resulting list as if it had been part of the original command line in the first place:

```
env -S ' /bin/zsh -o pipefail'
# works the same as:
env /bin/zsh -o pipefail
```

In less simple cases you'll have to quote some characters (`env -S` treats spaces, `"`, `'`, `\`, `$` specially, among others). In particular, it does *not* work like shell quoting. For details refer to the manual pages linked above.

Comment: Using `/usr/bin/env` has a split-string option that is a semi-portable way of doing this. My shebang then becomes `#!/usr/bin/env -S /bin/zsh -o pipefail`. This is my preferred solution now, consider adding it to your answer.